# how to transfer text from activity class to non activity class

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two classes. One is subclass of Activity and other is not allowed to be subclass of Activity. This is my code

```
public class CandidateGreetActivity extends Activity {
private EditText mEdit;
private mOk;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
   setContentView(R.layout.cand_greet_view);
   mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_view);
   mOk = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    mOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
}
```

}

I want to Transfer this text to non activity class once the button is clicked and this data will store by non activity class. Please help?

Comment: Just to confirm, do you want to transfer mEdit's text to a separate java class?

Comment: @HoraceHeaven Yes but this java class is not activity so i cannot use methods like startActivityForResult()

Comment: Just create a setText method in your non activity class. See my answer below.

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason you want to set your OnClickListener again every time onResume() is called? It would normally be better to set it just once in onCreate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CandidateGreetActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText mEdit;
    private mOk;
    private MyNonActivityClass myNonActivityClass;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.cand_greet_view);
        mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_view);
        mOk = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

        // create a new instance of your non activity class
        myNonActivityClass = new MyNonActivityClass();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // use the setText() method to pass the text
                myNonActivityClass.setText(mEdit.getText().toString())
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your non activity class create a setText method to take the text and assign it to a class variable.

```
public class MyNonActivityClass {

    private String mText;

    // constructor
    public MyNonActivityClass {
    }

    // method to receive text
    public void setText(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just Modify one thing:

Comment: Use Static Declaration of method otherwise context of class is changed.I mean like  this                                                         private static String mText;                                        public static void setText(String text).                        Call this by:                                            MyNonActivityClass.setText("value")...Cheers

Comment: Yes, correct. If you don't want to instantiate MyNonActivityClass in your activity, then you can set the method and class level variable as static to access them as you've suggested.